# dojox mobile button is much slower to click in v1.7.x

Tags: button, mobile, dojo, performance

Is it just me or is it that the dojox mobile button click is much slower in dojo 1.7.x?
I don't seem to notice other widgets slowing down. After upgrading my phonegap/dojo to the latest dojo 1.7.2 (using amd loader and a custom build) with phonegap 1.7.0. Only the mobile button widget seems to be really slow!?!?

Now the screen has many buttons (~12 buttons and 4 textbox widgets) and for some reason there seem to be a delay between the moment I press the button till the operation of writing into the textbox actually happens, the "animation" on the click is also delayed. I did try setting data-dojo-props="duration:150" on these buttons, but I still feel there is a huge lag in response for the same html screen that worked much faster with dojo 1.6.

Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Guy

Answer (score 3):

Try to set "mblIosWorkaround:false" to your djConfig/data-dojo-config, which
disable some tricky code to avoid flicker issue on iOS webkit.

In 1.8, there will be an another improvement regarding touch response,see this ticket:
http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/14604
I hope be helpful
Regards.